# having http links on https page but not scripts or css

Tags: php, ssl, https

I have a few http links (internal absolute) on my magento https page. Is it ok to have them for my SSL certificate to be displayed with correct padlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having links to non-http pages is fine. **LOADING** things from non-https urls is a big nono.

At most the user will get a warning about transitioning from a secure to a non-secure page, but it won't affect the padlock on the page.

Comment: That's great thanks. Is there any good online SSL page checker which will tell you what needs to be done on the page with error details?

Comment: What kind of errors? If it's a mixed-source message, you can use something like firefox's `Tools -> Page Info` menu option to see all loaded external resources and their urls.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP links won't break the padlock. Loading assets (images, scripts, stylesheets) into the page via an unencrypted URL will, though. As long as you aren't actually loading unencrypted content into the page, the page won't throw any warnings about insecure content.